# Restrict query_posts by Date?

Tags: query-posts

To display the most popular posts based on page views I am using this code ([source](http://www.be-studios.com/blog/2011/11/30/wordpress-display-most-popular-viewed-posts-without-a-plugin/)):

```
<?php
    query_posts('meta_key=post_views_count&orderby=meta_value_num&order=DESC');
    if (have_posts()) : while (have_posts()) : the_post(); ?>
    <li><a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a></li>
    <?php
    endwhile; endif;
    wp_reset_query();
?>
```

I would like to restrict the query to return posts from a certin date (i.e. the last seven days) and I am unsure how I would achieve this.

Comment: Please.... **don't use bold everywhere**... doesn't make your question more important. And please [don't use `query_posts()`](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/1753/when-should-you-use-wp-query-vs-query-posts-vs-get-posts).

Comment: I never claimed it made it more important, I was simply highlighting what the actual question was.  But I'll change it so it doesn't bother you so much.  Also - I thought this site's policy was only constructive answers?  Telling me not to use bold and not providing a workable answer isn't exactly constructive.

Comment: Have a look at [WP_Query()](https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query) -- there's a snippet of code there labeled *Returns posts for just the current week* that might be just what you're looking for.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've done something in the past using custom fields. Maybe this can get you going in the right direction? This is done directly after the `<?php while ( have_posts() ) : the_post(); ?>`

```
<?php
    $currentdate = date("Ymd");
    $expirationdate = genesis_get_custom_field('_racedate');
    $expirestring = str_replace("-","",$expirationdate);
        if (is_null($expirationdate)) {
            $expirestring = '30005050'; //MAKE UN-EXPIRING POSTS ALWAYS SHOW UP;

        } else {

        if (is_array($expirationdate)) {
            $expirestringarray = implode($expirationdate);
        }

        } //else
        if ( $expirestring + 1 > $currentdate ): ?>
```

This will actually show up everything that has been posted (in my case, future races) and a day after the "racedate", the post would disappear from the loop (it still remains in the dashboard).